# MaxLength Attribute in EF4.3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, .net-4.5

```
 The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute' 
 exists in both 

 [path...]\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll 

 and

'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework
\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'
```

Now, I have read [on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/fab7a591-f790-4064-aeb5-c320eb5057e5) that its safe to exclude the EntityFramework reference (which was added through the nuget package). However, when I do that, I cant create a DBContext properly as the DbModelBuilder class lives in the EntityFramework dll. Also, some other critical classes are missing when I remove the EntityFramework refference so this is old and irrelevant solution now.

**Update (disambiguation)**: Both `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` and `EntityFramework.dll`  include `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute`. The problem is that each dll also includes other classes that are critical to EF code-first design. For example:

```
EntityFramework.dll:
 - System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder

System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll:
 - System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this statement to top of your class

```
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace is distibuted across the `EntityFramework.dll` and `System.ComponontModel.DataAnnotations.dll`. So you need to add a reference to both of that in your project to make use of DataAnnotations.

The MaxLenth attribute is present in `EntityFramework.dll`. So make sure you have that reference to that dll present in your project references section.

[image]

**EDIT :** As of .NET framework 4.5, this namespace is moved to the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`. So If you use .NET Framework 4.5 with Entity Framework 4.3.1 or less, You will run in to this conflict. The solution is to switch to Entity framework 1.50 beta 1/ 2 release if you want to stick with .NET 4.5 or downgrade to .NET 4 to use EntityFramework 4.3.1.

From the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) documentations.

> Starting with Entity Framework 5.0 Beta 1, the EntityFramework.dll
>   does not contain definitions for data annotations. These definitions
>   were moved to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll and are
>   defined in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but please read the question again. The problem I have is that I need both dll,  and I have the refference and the using statement set, but that fact creates a conflict. System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute is also present in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll . Ill edit to include that info

Comment: @MihalisBagos: I got your problem. It is because .NEt 4.5 has this namespace inside the DataAnnotations.dll. So you should change your EF version according to that.See my updated answer.

Comment: Doh now it makes sense, thanks! I was trying to understand what I did wrong...  Command for nuget package is Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre for what it's worth

Comment: I was already on EF 5.0 but .NET 4.  By changing my project to .NET 4.5, I started seeing this problem.  My EntityFramework reference was pointing to .NET4.0 as can be seen in the path of the reference:  packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll.  To fix, I deleted the reference and my packages.config file and started over.  Fixed.

Comment: @Shyju - i just ran into this issue today. I'm basically trying to upgrade my application from .NET 4.0 -> .NET 4.5. But i wanted to upgrade EF later on (less things to worry about for a single build). But through reading this answer/comments, it sounds like that it not possible?

Comment: @RPM1984 Sorry it's a bit late but we solved it by not using any of the affected attributes, which are:

Column,
ComplexType,
DatabaseGenerated,
DatabaseGeneratedOption,
ForeignKey,
InverseProperty,
MaxLength,
MinLength,
NotMapped,
and Table.

MinLength and MaxLength can usually be replaced with StringLength (which has a MinimumLength argument) and the rest are usually used for custom EF/DB mappings rather than validation, so you can substitute by overriding DbContext.OnModelCreated and specify any custom mappings there instead.

Comment: I'm not sure why Microsoft have released a version of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll with exactly the same public key and version number. Wouldn't all of this have been bypassed if they'd incremented one of the lower version numbers when they released the new one, so we could still point to the old one when using EF 4.3.1?

Answer (score 7):

I didn't have the option of upgrading the project to use EF5, or downgrading the build machine to .Net Framework 4.

There is a way to solve this though! It turns out when you install Visual Studio 2012 it adds the following folder (amongst others).

**C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0**

In VS if you open a project targetting 4.0 and look at the properties of your reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations you'll see that the path is pointing to the above location, rather than the GAC.

This folder contains the original Framework 4.0 assemblies. If they're present on the machine then MSBuild etc., upon building a project targeting 4.0 will reference these rather than the modified ones that 4.5 puts into the GAC.

In our case this meant we could fix the problem by copying that folder from a dev machine with VS installed up to our build server in the same location. (N.b. We only needed to copy this folder, there was no need to install VS on the build server).

More info here: http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/iterator-blocks-missing-methods-and-net.html

Hope this helps someone else!