# EF 5 on .NET 4 The type 'DatabaseGeneratedOption' exists in both

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0

Recently I added identity column to one of my table:

```
this.Property(t => t.GatewayId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

I tried this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552444/942637.
But still I get the following error when I browse my website:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type
'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption' exists in both
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\09b33b19\15db599\assembly\dl3\626c4b05\eddd55c2_9c3ace01\EntityFramework.DLL'
and
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'
```

I'm using .NET 4 and EF 5. Of course my project refer to EF 4.4 because the latest version which is suppoted by .NET 4 is EF 4.4.
My website works fine without above line.

Comment: Dublicated question from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183944/entity-framework-5-on-net-4-0-databasegeneratedoption-identity-is-undefined

Comment: Do you have .NET 4.5 installed? Are you using VS 2012?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: I'm using VS2012 and .NET 4.0. Also, I have .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: @RameshRajendran: My project compiles without any error, but when I run it, it gives me the error. Also, in the link you mentioned, it says doesn't exist in .NET 4.0. My error says that it exists but in two assemblies. But I tried the solution in that link (reinstalling EF) and it worked. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling of EF through NUGET but it did not work.

Comment: Any solution found for this? I have the issue when my solution is building on TeamCity, no problem when compiling and running it locally in Visual Studio or IIS Express.

Comment: This question is too old and unfortunately I can't remember what fixed my problem, but I remember some files in a specific folder in my project had property "Build Action" set to "Content" instead of "Compile"!! It happens sometimes when you add a folder that includes some source codes in it in older version of visual studio. This causes strange errors in your projects and hard to find the exact problem.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12599605/35133 fixed this for me - basically uninstall the Entity Framework NuGet package, then reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

Installing EntityFrameWork did the trick for me. `VS -> Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console`, type in the Package Manager Console:

[image]

**Install-Package EntityFramework (or latest -Version 6.1.3)**

[image]