# System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace conflict

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, namespaces

I am using MVC 4, .net 4, and Entity Framework 6. My projects are building on my dev machine which has Visual Studio 2010 installed but on my build server I get a namespace conflict...

*The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' exists in both 'd:\Projects\tools\Apps\LAMS\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'*

I'm unsure how to resolve this conflict and I do not understand why I do not receive the conflict on my dev machine.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't have something referencing .NET 4.5+ somewhere? `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` wasn't added to .NET until 4.5

Comment: I've uninstalled 4.5 from the build server. My solution does not reference it anyway but if it did I would expect to get other build errors after removing it. I do not but I still have the error I detailed above. Do you have any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

.NET 4.0 really shouldn't include `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` so it's a little baffling that you'd get a reference conflict, but apparently .NET 4.5 overwrites 4.0 assemblies.

You can find more information in this [post by Marc Gravell](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2012/09/iterator-blocks-missing-methods-and-net.html) which states:

> fact 1: 4.5 is an in-place over-the-top install on top of 4.0, in the GAC; once you have installed 4.5, 4.0 runs with the 4.5 assemblies
>
> fact 2: if your build server doesn’t have the reference assemblies, it looks in the GAC – so… once you’ve installed 4.5, it will get 4.5 even if you asked (in your project) for 4.0

### Solution

On your development machine, Visual Studio adds a different folder that is used for referencing .NET 4.0 assemblies, which is something like

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

You can copy that folder over to your build machine, and it should work since MSBuild will reference these when building a project targeting 4.0.

On the other hand, since you have uninstalled .NET 4.5 on your build machine, maybe just reinstalling .NET 4.0 would work as well.

*Also, see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14997666/4812586).*

Comment: Thanks for your answer you've added a lot of clarity to my situation. What I did find odd though was that the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll assembly in the buildservers GAC was still targeting .net 4.0.3 but did have the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace in it. The version of this assembly in my local reference library was also targeting 4.0.3 but did not have the schema namespace. If the assembly on the buildservers GAC was from the .net 4.5 install I'd expect it to target 4.5 (using reflector to look at assembly manifest).